# BxSlider conflict using 2 functions

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Works fine on load but on resize breaks.
I guess it something to do with use of the below function. I'm using it twice, and if I use it once works fine. It might be a conflict.

```
mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(settings());

function resizeCarousel() {
  mySlider.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
      startSlide: mySlider.getCurrentSlide()
  }));
}

$(window).resize(resizeCarousel);
```

please Have ad look my **demo** and try to resize it and check console log.

http://jsfiddle.net/wd73T/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery Bxslider error on resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477213/jquery-bxslider-error-on-resize)

Comment: @A. Wolff it's a much precise question from the previous one and also different as gives another explanation. Just hope somebody could help

Comment: Breaks how? Your fiddle seems fine !